# New arraylist item overwrites previous listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

Currently I'm trying to send intent data from user input to display onto my custom adapter. The intent data from user input from the detailspage.java class will be sent to the listview page with custom Arrayadapter. However each time i add a new item it overwrites my previous entries. Hope some kind souls can help someone new to android.

Below are snippets of my code.

```
    // Set a click listener on that button
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveExercise(exerciseName);
        }
    });
}

private void saveExercise(String name) {
    // Read from input fields
    // Use trim to eliminate leading or trailing white space
    String setString = mSetEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String repString = mRepEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String nameString = name;


    Intent intent = new Intent(ExerciseDetailActivity.this, WorkoutSetActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", nameString);
    intent.putExtra("set", setString);
    intent.putExtra("rep", repString);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

The intent data will be sent to the activity page to initiate the custom ArrayAdapter.

```
public class WorkoutSetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<WorkoutSet> workout = new ArrayList<WorkoutSet>();

/** Adapter for the ListView */
WorkoutSetAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercise_list);

    adapter = new WorkoutSetAdapter(this, workout);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    String name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    String set = intent.getExtras().getString("set");
    String rep = intent.getExtras().getString("rep");

    adapter.add(new WorkoutSet(name,set,rep));
    Toast.makeText(WorkoutSetActivity.this, "Workout added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Lastly the custom ArrayAdapter code. This is where I set the custom listview.

```
public class WorkoutSetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WorkoutSet> {


public WorkoutSetAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<WorkoutSet> workout) {
    super(context, 0, workout);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.activity_workout_set, parent, false);
    }

    WorkoutSet currentWorkout = getItem(position);

    // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.workout_name);
    TextView setTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.workout_set);
    TextView repTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.workout_rep);

    nameTextView.setText(currentWorkout.getName());
    setTextView.setText("Sets: "+ currentWorkout.getSet());
    repTextView.setText("Reps: "+ currentWorkout.getRep());

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

Comment: You should use some persistent data storage...

Answer (score 0):

> each time i add a new item it overwrites my previous entries

There are no "previous entries". `startActivity` loads an empty adapter each time and you only add one element.

What you want is a [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) (or any persistent storage layer, but SQLite is provided without more libraries).

---

On the plus side, your Intent and Adapter code look fine.

Comment: Hey there thanks for your feedback awhile back. Tried implementing the database over the week but i ran into some problems. If you have the time do give it a look. Would really appreciate the help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329936/inserting-data-into-sqlite-and-displaying-into-listview?noredirect=1#comment71812487_42329936

Answer (score 0):

Every time，you call `startActivity ()`, you open a new `WorkoutSetActivity`, it's a new WorkoutSetActivity object instance, so the arrayAdapter is also  new one, it will only display the data you send this time.

If you want to display all the data, you must save the previous data to database or file. At WorkoutSetActivity onCreate (), you should get the previous data, put them and current data to the adapter.